# Open an activity with a fragment on it?

Tags: android, menu, fragment

I am trying to open an activity with an menu, this works, without any problems. however, when i put an fragment on the activity i open, i get this error

```
06-19 16:38:46.253    2732-2732/com.example.broodjepoep.stapvoorstap E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.broodjepoep.stapvoorstap, PID: 2732
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.broodjepoep.stapvoorstap/com.example.broodjepoep.stapvoorstap.LayoutFragmentOne}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.broodjepoep.stapvoorstap.LayoutFragmentOne.onCreate(LayoutFragmentOne.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: you need to implement senddata method
            at com.example.broodjepoep.stapvoorstap.FirstFragment.onAttach(FirstFragment.java:56)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:849)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1040)
            at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1142)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4786)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:689)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.setContentView(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:228)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.setContentView(ActionBarActivity.java:102)
            at com.example.broodjepoep.stapvoorstap.LayoutFragmentOne.onCreate(LayoutFragmentOne.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2271)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1205)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

fwef

code behind menu item click

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings)
        {
            return true;
        }


        Intent iOne = new Intent(this,LayoutFragmentOne.class);
        Intent iTwo = new Intent(this,LayoutFragmentTwo.class);

        switch(id)
        {
            case R.id.fragOne:
                startActivity(iOne);
                return true;
            case R.id.fragTwo:
                startActivity(iTwo);
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

LayoutFragmentOne.class

```
package com.example.broodjepoep.stapvoorstap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

/**
 * Created by Pizza on 19-6-2015.
 */
public class LayoutFragmentOne extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_fragment_one);
    }
}
```

LayoutFragmentTwo.class

```
package com.example.broodjepoep.stapvoorstap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

/**
 * Created by Pizza on 19-6-2015.
 */
public class LayoutFragmentTwo extends ActionBarActivity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_fragment_two);
    }
}
```

if i put two fragments on MainActivity, there is no error and i can communicate between them without any problems. The problem only occurs when i try to start an activity **With a fragment on it**

is this a known problem, or is there a known fix?

I dont know if it is needed, but here are the code behind Fragment one and Fragment two

One:

```
package com.example.broodjepoep.stapvoorstap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

/**
 * Created by Pizza on 19-6-2015.
 */
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment
{
    SendMessage sm;
    Button btnSendData;
    EditText tb1;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one,container,false);
        btnSendData = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnSendData);
        tb1 = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.tb1);
        btnSendData.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                String message;
                message = tb1.getText().toString();
                sm.sendData(message);
            }
        });
        return v;

    }



    interface SendMessage
    {
        public void sendData(String message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity)
    {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try
        {
            sm = (SendMessage) activity;
        }
        catch (ClassCastException e)
        {
            throw  new ClassCastException("you need to implement senddata method");
        }
    }
}
```

Two:

```
package com.example.broodjepoep.stapvoorstap;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by Pizza on 14-6-2015.
 */
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment
{
    TextView txt;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View v;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two,container,false);
        txt = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        return v;
    }
    public void getData(String message)
    {
        txt.setText(message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty clear:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: you need to implement senddata method
```

Which happens when a fragment is being attached to an activity that does not implement the said interface. It's all written in this code:

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity)
{
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try
    {
        sm = (SendMessage) activity;
    }
    catch (ClassCastException e)
    {
        throw  new ClassCastException("you need to implement senddata method");
    }
}
```

The activity that wants to use the fragment with such code, should implement the interface:

```
public class LayoutFragmentOne extends ActionBarActivity implements SendMessage
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_fragment_one);
    }

    @Override
    public void sendData(String message) {

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! i'm still not a pro with android :s, and i really don't like the debugger in android studio. i like the debugger in visual studio much more, but thats a personal opinion i guess. Learning from mistakes :) Thanks again :)